# spring cloud dataflow - detect running task

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using spring cloud data flow (1.3.0.RELEASE). I would like to detect a running task in order to prevent multiple instances of the same task being started.

I was looking at the task execution status features, specifically "End Time" but i noticed that sometimes task execution status can have "Start Time" set along with "Exit Code" set to 0 and "End Time" not set.
Because of that, "End Time" does not look like a viable deciding factor.

[Task execution list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsuhN.png)

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the SCDF level, we don't (yet) have the native ability to control it as part of the orchestration layer. A few options are possible, though.

1) You could have the Task applications emit its [lifecycle events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task-events) via `task-events` destination (queue or topic); it could be the standard types or custom events. A stream could then be used as a decision point to trigger the subsequent launches.

2) In the recent [2.0 M3 release of Spring Cloud Task](https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/14/spring-cloud-task-2-0-0-m3-is-now-available), we can restrict the launch of multiple Task instances of the same type. This could effectively be controlled by the `spring.cloud.task.singleInstanceEnabled=true` for each Task launches. With this flag set, while launching the Task instances, the lock-check would automatically be applied. Thus the duplicate or unintended launches can be prevented.

3) If you cannot switch to 2.0 M3, you could, in theory, replicate #2 solution from above on your 1.x based Task applications.

Comment: Thanks, option 2 could be what i need.